# lldb: error: summary string parsing error

Tags: c++, windows, clang, llvm, lldb

So I'm running windows with llvm and msvc. When I compile my program with clang++ and try to debug it with lldb and inspect a string variable I get "error: summary string parsing error".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string a = "Lorem ipsum\n";
    std::cout << a;
}
```

```
Process 8652 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x00007ff671e1102a main.exe`main at main.cpp:245
   3  int main()
   4  {
   5          std::string a = "Lorem ipsum\n";
-> 6          std::cout << a;
   7  }
(lldb) v a
(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >) a = error: summary string parsing error
```

I already tried adding -fstandalone-debug to my compile flags but it still didn't work

info for the tools I use

```
C:\Users\Me>clang++ --version
clang version 16.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin

C:\Users\Me>lldb --version
lldb version 16.0.6
```

Comment: What does `v --raw` show for the variable?  If that seems weird, and you can't find the string guts showing "Loren ipsum" in there, then probably there is some problem with optimization.  If the variable seems reasonable, then it might be that we aren't picking the right std::string formatter.  I doubt the clang STL and the msvc one are laid out the same way.  You can see which formatter is being used with `type summary info <varname>`.

Comment: When I type `type summary info a` it gives me this `summary applied to (std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >) a is: ${var._M_dataplus._M_p} (hide value)`

Comment: I also saw the "guts" of the string when I did `v --raw`

Comment: So the "std::string" data summary that lldb found expects the field _M_dataplus._M_p?  Was that present in the raw output?  That doesn't look like the  way the llvm-project's STL names members.  This might be the wrong STL's data formatter?

Comment: Indeed, they were not present in the raw output. Instead, fields like `_Ptr`, `_Alias`, `_Buf`, `_Mypair`, and others were there. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: @JimIngham still haven't fixed the issue can't find anything about this issue anywhere else. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I don't see those fields in any of the std::string formatters built into lldb.  The "summary formatters" lldb uses to present STL types in a readable way have to be done by hand for each STL implementation, and it looks like the one you are using hasn't been supported yet.  More on the summary format is here: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html#summary-strings

Comment: @JimIngham Thank you for responding I guess I'll just have to wait until lldb supports the STL implementation I use.

Comment: Supporting an STL implementation is a fair bit of work, and since lldb is an open source project, supporting whatever library you are using will require someone to move that project forward.  At least file an ER with https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues requesting this support to get that conversation going.

Comment: Okie will do so now.